# How to execute a bash script into a makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a simple bash script, that install and zip a NodeJS application. It's worked great local. Now I want to execute this script from a Makefile. So I wrote this code

```
.FOO: install_and_zip
    install_and_zip: ./install_and_zip_foo.sh
```

So if I run this Makefile with `make foo` I'm getting this error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `foo'.  Stop.
```

Makefile and bash script are in the same directory.

What I'm doing wrong? Can you help me to fix this Makefile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different errors. This will work:

```
foo:    install_and_zip
install_and_zip:
# next line must start with a real TAB (ASCII 9)
    ./install_and_zip_foo.sh
```

- If you want to make `foo`, then call the rule `foo`, but not `FOO` or `.FOO`.
- Code goes always below the rule. All command lines must start with a real TAB (ASCII 9, but not a series of spaces).

Rule `foo` calls rule `install_and_zip`. Is this your whish? Otherwise this will do it too:

```
foo:
# next line must start with a real TAB (ASCII 9)
    ./install_and_zip_foo.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I need only one rule to execute only one script. I tried out your solution `foo:
    ./install_and_zip_foo.sh` with `make foo` but I get this error `Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: 2 lines! And a TAB at start of the second line.

Comment: That's a "real" horizontal tab-character, e.g. `ASCII 0x9`, not just 8-spaces.

Comment: I inserted TABS here, but they were replaced by spaces. Every command line must start with a TAB to distinguish rules and other Make components from and commands.

Answer (score 1):

You should write "make .FOO" as you have defined it to be that way. However, you have to properly write your Makefile (tab identations and so on). If you do, you can just write 'make' and the tool will identify "install_and_zip" as the main target, thus executing your script.

PD: targets with a leading '.' (and without slashes) will be ignored by make when trying to identify the main goal (i.e. they won't run just executing 'make'). So, unless you know what you are doing, just rename your target to 'foo'.